# couldn't save which view has focus because the focused view has no id

Tags: android, android-activity

I am having problem when i am trying to dial a number from my app. I have a button in a map activity which is under an activity group, clicking which i want to call 911. but, when i click the button, i have seen in the log cat that the button is clicked, but dialing activity is not launched. The problem i've seen in the logcat is:

> couldn't save which view has focus because the focused view
>   com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow$DecorView@437e0ab8 has no
>   id.

Here is the code:

```
    btnDial.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            String toDial = "tel:911";
            Intent myIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_CALL,Uri.parse(toDial));
            //myIntent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
            MyMapActivity.this.getParent().startActivity(myIntent);
            Log.d("MyMapActivity", "Dial button is called.......................");
        }
    });
```

I have tried it with setting `FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK`, with `getParent.startActivity(myIntent)`, with `MyMapActivity.this.startActivity(myIntent)`, but nothing works.
Here is the stack trace,

```
04-21 14:07:28.187: D/MyMapActivity(767): Dial button is called.......................
04-21 13:44:42.416: D/PhoneWindow(444): couldn't save which view has focus because the focused view com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow$DecorView@437e0ab8 has no id.
```

Answer (score 1):

I had similar problem and I found out that in my case the problem was caused by a EditText that was requesting focus but was not focused to.

Check your activity if you have anything similar and just remove the request focus

Answer (score 0):

i think this a problem to add Call permission in your Androidmanifest. Add this permission in androidmanifrst.

`<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.CALL_PHONE"></uses-permission>`

Comment: this permission was added in the manifest. I think, not declaring proper permissions in the manifest produces Security Exception, which is not my problem. thanks for your reply.

Comment: you need start call Intent. like this    Phone.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

   public void onClick(View v) {
    Intent sIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_CALL, Uri.parse("tel:919894643826"));
    startActivity(sIntent);
   }
  });

Answer (score 0):

try to look at this answer:[onactivityresult not getting called while using Gallery in android](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14152638/onactivityresult-not-getting-called-while-using-gallery-in-android)
it works on me also. We put the parent of out activity.
Hope this will help you too.